# check if (child) form is dirty in nested reactive forms

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, formbuilder

I have a form with different sections (nested formgroups)
How can you check if something changes in a specific section.

HTML:

```
<div [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <div formGroupName="one">
    <input type="text" formControlName="email">
    <input type="text" formControlName="name">
   <div>
</div>
```

TS:

```
 export class someClass implements OnInit {
  
  formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    one: this.formBuilder.group({
      email: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$')]],
      name[null],
      })
  });

 get emailControl(): AbstractControl { return this.formGroup.get('one.email'); }
 get nameControl(): AbstractControl { return this.formGroup.get('one.name'); }

...
}
```

for example if I want a class (style) if the form is dirty, I can do something like:

[class.dirty]="formGroup.dirty"

How can I check if the "one" form is dirty?

Answer (score 1):

Angular will automatically adds control class, If form is dirty, you can use that class to style as per your need.

```
div.ng-dirty{
....
}
```

[For More Information](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#control-status-css-classes)

Comment: Nice. I also have some complex components. and I have to do something with the parent component/div of the div (which contains the form). In other words the class must be set on a few levels higher and I won't use jquery.

Comment: Then you can use formGroup dirty property to set class dynamically as mentioned in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the group dirtiness by calling

```
formGroup.get('one').dirty
```

That returns the `FormGroup` as `AbstractControl`, thus with standard control props accessible.